# Accessing string that was passed as argument causes stack buffer overflow

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, stack-overflow

I'm studying C at uni and am trying to access the string (the string representation of a binary-number) that was passed into a function to convert it into the integer-representation of that string.

Eg. `"011"` should return `3`.

The string is the first 3 bits in a bitstream that's inputted in reverse.

```
char * temp_holder = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);

int index_of_holder = 0;
for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
    printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    temp_holder[index_of_holder] = buffer[i];
}
printf("\n");

int decimalValue = fromBinaryToInt(&temp_holder, 3);
printf("DECIMAL_VALUE: %d\n", decimalValue);
```

The `fromBinaryToInt` function is:

```
int fromBinaryToInt(char *string[], int length){

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%c", *string[i]);
    }

    int int_rep = strtol(*string, (char **)NULL, 2);

    printf("REP: %d\n", int_rep);

    return int_rep;
}
```

The subsequent error I get is:

==21==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffda9f47a08 at pc 0x000000500cdf bp 0x7ffda9f47980 sp 0x7ffda9f47978
- READ of size 8 at 0x7ffda9f47a08 thread T0

I thought this could be due to the null-terminating character so I played around with modifying the `length` variable (+/- 1) in the `for-loop` within `fromBinaryToInt` but that hasn't changed anything.

I also considered the for-loop only accessing the first element and nothing more - but my understanding is I've sent through the memory address and the length of the block so the for-loop should have access to the indexes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Cheers :)

Comment: `char * temp_holder = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);` => `char temp_holder[4];`.

Comment: but the problem is passing a pointer to the array to `fromBinaryToInt` => just pass in `temp_holder` as `char *string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, bug in below line,  `index_of_holder` remains same all the time, please increment it.

```
temp_holder[index_of_holder] = buffer[i];
```

Secondly, in `fromBinaryToInt()` `string` is single pointer only so you can't do `*string[i]);` in the next `printf` statement.

Here is the working code

```
int fromBinaryToInt(char *string, int length){

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                printf("%c", string[i] ); /*since string is single pointer now you can do like before you did */
        }

        int int_rep = strtol(string, (char **)NULL, 2);

        printf("REP: %d\n", int_rep);

        return int_rep;
}
int main() {
        char * temp_holder = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
        char buffer[4] ="011";
        int index_of_holder = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
                printf("%c", buffer[i]);
                temp_holder[index_of_holder] = buffer[i];
                index_of_holder++;
        }
        printf("\n");

        int decimalValue = fromBinaryToInt(temp_holder, 3);/* no need to pass address of temp_holder */
        printf("DECIMAL_VALUE: %d\n", decimalValue);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bloody hell - realised the incremental error and rushed back here to answer what the problem was but thank you very much. I don't understand though why you've added 48?

Comment: @Pembroke: Adding 48 is [achal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5346306/achal)”s attempt to convert a simple number (like 0, 1, or 2) to a character code (like the codes for “0”, “1”, or “2”). However, your source suggests you have actual character codes already, not simple numbers. Additionally, 48 assumes ASCII. More properly `'0'`, meaning the character code for “0” in the implementation, would be used.

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil I was in hurry so I didn't put correct one. now updated.

Comment: @Pembroke thanks for your compliment, Bloody hell !! It was nice one.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
int index_of_holder = 0;
for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
    printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    temp_holder[index_of_holder] = buffer[i];
}
```

`index_of_holder` is never changed, so all the characters are put in `temp_holder[0]`. The rest of `temp_holder` remains uninitialized.

This:

```
int fromBinaryToInt(char *string[], int length)
```

declares `string` to be an array of pointers to `char`. It is indeed passed `&temp_holder`, which may be considered to be a pointer to the first element of an array of one pointer to `char`. However, a more normal usage is to declare a simple pointer to `char`

```
int fromBinaryToInt(char *string, int length)
```

and pass it `temp_holder`, as in `fromBinaryToInt(temp_holder, 3)`.

As it is, where it is used here:

```
printf("%c", *string[i]);
```

This takes element `i` of the array. When `i` is 0 in the loop, that is fine, it takes the first element, which exists and is a pointer to `char`, and then deferences it with `*` and prints that. However, when `i` is 1, it attempts to take the second element of the array. That element does not exist, and the resulting behavior is undefined.

If the parameter were merely `char *string`, then this `printf` could be:

```
printf("%c", string[i]);
```

and, in calling `strtol`, you would simply pass `string` rather than `*string`:

```
int int_rep = strtol(string, (char **)NULL, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for the in-depth answer, much appreciated!